# Swift 4.2 - __shared attribute near type

Tags: swift

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double?changes=latest_minor
In updated version of class definition I found init method for Double with NSNumber near type the unknown keyword `__shared`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 8):

The `__shared` parameter annotation means that a *value type* parameter can be passed by reference.

For *value types*, this enables us to elide a copy before we make the call and instead pass a reference pointing right at the memory we allocated. SIL calls this convention `in_guaranteed` for (indirect reference with guaranteed lifetime). It's currently the way we pass self in non-mutating functions.

It was introduced by the [Ownership Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#shared-values).

Here is the difference between the ownership annotations:

- `inout`: mutating pointer-like value
- `__shared`: non-mutating pointer-like value
- `__owned`: an explicit way of writing the default

Here is a summary of the manifesto: [Swift Ownership Manifesto TL;DR](https://gist.github.com/Gankro/1f79fbf2a9776302a9d4c8c0097cc40e).

Comment: The tl;dr link is broken.